# App-debug.html not working on eu1.rallydev.com

Tags: rally, code-rally

I'm currently developing a custom app that needs to be deployed on the eu1.rallydev.com server.

During the development I would like to use the App-debug.html to quickly see code changes without having to build and paste new html code, but this doesn't work.

I've changed the "server" in config.json, but keeps getting an error in console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

Does anyone know what else I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the sysadmin has blocked the Custom HTML app in the subscription settings:

Allow Custom HTML app: true
Enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing: true